# Failed to get external storage files directory for Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

Tags: android, scoped-storage

In the app, I have implemented download manager to download new app version (APK file) and then install it. I've recently migrated to scoped storage in order to use app's private external directory. This is the code:

```
private void setupDownloadRequest() {
    mDownloadRequest = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(mDownloadUrl));
    mDownloadRequest.setTitle(mFileName);
    mDownloadRequest
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    mDownloadRequest.setMimeType(getMimeType());
    mDownloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(mActivity, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, mFileName);
}
```

The process works well on Android <10 and also on emulator with Android 10. After release, I'm seeing the crash only on Huawei Mate 9 and Xiaomi MI8 (Android 9 and 10):

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get external storage files directory
    at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(DownloadManager.java:782)
    ...
```

Looking at the code in Android SDK (API 29), directory seems to be missing:

```
public Request setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(Context context, String dirType,
        String subPath) {
    final File file = context.getExternalFilesDir(dirType);
    if (file == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to get external storage files directory");
    ...
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this? Is `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS` directory missing on some devices, shouldn't it be created automatically?

Before download, I check that the permission `Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is granted.

Comment: The path of getExternalFilesDir(null) should be there automatically but getExternalFilesDir("Download") not. But it might be created if you call this function. If not then create it yourself. Its a strange story as i have found DownloadManager to always create non existing directories

Comment: `String dirType` Is that really called type? How confusing! Its only used as name for subfolder.

Comment: I see, so `getExternalFilesDir(null)` should point to the root of the app's external storage? If this solves the issue, I can do that.

Comment: yeah name `dirType` is quite consufing!

Comment: So do some tests to see if the directory is created in those devices by calling getExternalFilesDir("Micer").

Comment: No it does not point to the root. It points to your apps external files dir. Have a look at getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath().

Comment: I do not know if the download manager accepts a null there but you could always try.

Comment: It's working well on emulator and OnePlus5 with Android 9, with any folder name or "" for root. So not sure why it's crashing on some real devices. I have no way to test this unfortunately. But I got a crash in Crashlytics on Android 9 too, so it's not Android 10 specific.

Comment: Why not using `MediaStore` to save the file into `Download` for API 29+?

Answer (score -1):

Add  **android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"** in your manifest Application tag for Android 10 Devices

Comment: That does not help and is never needed for an app specific directory like getExternalFilesDir().

Comment: yep, if I understand it well `requestLegacyExternalStorage` is for public external directory (I have app specific external dir) and this flag will be ignored on Android 11

Comment: Also I have no issues on Emulator with Android 10 without this flag.